# Programmatically use Gmail to receive e-mail?

Tags: .net, smtp, gmail, imap, pop3

I'd like to use a C# program to poll a gmail account and automatically download new messages. I know you can use gmail as an outbound SMTP server, but is there any way to access new messages sent to the account?

**EDIT:** Thanks for the rapid feedback....so I have two options, POP or IMAP.

Which one should I use? And why?

**EDIT #2:** Looks like IMAP allows me to not have to poll. Looks like the way to go.

Comment: By the way, there is an instruction how to use SMTP with SSL with GMail: http://www.mono-project.com/FAQ:_Security#Does_SSL_works_for_SMTP.2C_like_GMail_.3F

Comment: "IMAP allows me to not have to poll" - how so?

"Which one should I use" - each has its pros and cons. This would require a question of its own...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use [Gmail with IMAP](http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=75725&topic=12891).

Comment: Sure - but with what libraries does Jonathan use IMAP?

Comment: What about this one?

Shows how to get list of unread messages (IMAP, VB.NET)
http://blog.rebex.net/news/archive/2007/05/28/howto-get-list-of-unread-messages-from-an-imap-server-in-vb-net.aspx

Shows how to get message list from POP3 server (C#)
http://blog.rebex.net/news/archive/2007/05/14/howto-download-emails-from-gmail-account-in-csharp.aspx

Answer (score 7):

You can [configure GMail to let you get at your mail with a POP3 client](http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=13273).

Answer (score 1):

You can get an [Atom Feed of your GMAIL](https://mail.google.com/mail/feed/atom), which can be fetched with a regular web request, and parse as a regular XML document. I made a PHP page I could access from my phone (which doesn't support Atom Feeds, or pages as advanced as Google Mobile), to show me a list of new emails.