# Full "API-ish" use of Gmail or other mail providers

Tags: gmail

Given the user credentials (username+password or OAuth tokens), what are the effective ways to programmatically **send and receive** mail (and notifications) on behalf of that user?

---

I searched around and saw:

1. using IMAP programmatically ( [Programmaticly use Gmail to receive e-mail?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/342106/programmaticly-use-gmail-to-receive-e-mail) )
2. OAuth

I am intimidated by the first method and I am unsure of the capabilities the OAuth API has.

Is there some (fourth party!) service that makes it easier by offering an API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gmail's IMAP supports OAuth and the JavaMail API -- [see here](http://code.google.com/p/google-mail-xoauth-tools/wiki/JavaSampleCode)

Answer (score 0):

Try Context.io a service which gives a RESTful API to email services